# Link/ Connect Android App to MS access db

Tags: android, database, ms-access

I am a novice and I would like to know how can I use my android app to connect to a local server over wifi to retrieve certain field a from a Microsoft access database? I have no idea of how to begin. If anyone has the slightest of idea I would appreciate your input. Thanks.

Comment: here is how to connect to sql server I hope you can find the way to connect to ms access based on this: http://www.tutecentral.com/restful-api-for-android-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

I'll talk about 3 completely different paths.

1. BARE BONES.
   This may sound ridiculously oversimplified, but it works and I use it all the time. You export your Access Table to a CSV file, copy the CSV to your Android phone, then use a good text editor app, like TurboEditorPRO, to Open and **Search** it. Easy as pie.
2. WEBPAGE.
   I don't know if you've ever written a program, or learned a software language.  I know some VBA and PHP. I learned just enough PHP and HTML to develop simple useful interactive webpages (Buttons, Listboxes, Textareas, reading/writing CSV files). **My custom webpages are my apps.**  PHP is about the same level of difficulty as Visual Basic for Application (VBA). I subscribe to Hosting/Domain on GoDaddy, I upload/download with FileZilla, I edit code with VIM for Windows.  For example, when I go out to play volleyball with my friends, I run my TeamMaker webpage, input the names of the players present, click MakeTeams, and it uses CSV files of my friend's ranks to randomly make teams. Love it.
3. ANDROID APP.
   You have to be seriously tech savvy to develop an app for a smartphone. Takes tons lots of google searches, installing development kits and compilers, programming skills, it's a real commitment.  I'm an amateur software developer, I've never done it, I would try it but it's too time consuming and high-maintenance.